# R error with MEPDF package inside function cube

Tags: r, function, ecdf

I want to build a bivariate empirical distribution function. I have found the package `MEPDF` which does the job I want, however I get an error even while using the example available from the help.

Here is a documentation for this package with the example I am having trouble:
[MEPDF Documentation](https://pure.manchester.ac.uk/ws/portalfiles/portal/85606937/MEPDFR.pdf)

Here is the code

```
data <- MASS::mvrnorm(100000, mu = c(0, 0), Sigma = diag(2))
density <- epdf(data,max_corner = c(2,2),
                min_corner = c(-2,-2),
                main_gridsize = c(0.05,0.05))
```

Inside the `epdf` function, the function `cube` is called and the following variable is created

```
char <- "X1"
  if (dim > 1) {
    for (i in 2:dim) {
      char <- paste(char, ",X", i, sep = "")
    }
  }
> char
[1] "X1,X2"
```

And finally I get an error on the following line

```
lst <- eval(parse(text = paste(".(", char, ")", sep = "")))
Error in .(X1, X2) : could not find function "."
```

This package was build under R 3.0 and I am using 4.1. I don't know if this could be a problem.

Comment: The function `.()` comes from `plyr`. You would need to have that package loaded if you want that code to work. Note that packages maintain their own namespaces where they can define functions or include functions from other packages without exporting them. It's not usually the case that you can just directly call code from inside package functions.

Comment: Thanks. Somehow I missed that, I had `dplyr` loaded